# how SliverList overlay on SliverAppBar in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

want to *avatar* part of floats on *image*
, *avatar* is with the following list or contents, and don't stretch when pull down

```
CustomScrollView
  slivers
    SliverAppBar
      flexibleSpace
        background: Image
    SliverList
      CircleAvatar
```

```
CustomScrollView(
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      floating: true,
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 120.0,
      stretch: true,
      stretchTriggerOffset: 150.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Image.network(indexData.banner, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 95,
                  height: 95,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(indexData.avatar),
                    radius: 42.5,
                  ),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      border: new Border.all(width: 5.0, color: blackLight),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(42.5)),
                      color: blackLight
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ] ,
        );
      }, childCount: 1 ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

*slivers* use *Stack* : *A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderStack.*

Why only *SliverList, SliverFixedExtentList, SliverGrid, SliverPadding, SliverAppBar...* can be used in *slivers*?

Answer (score -3):

[image]

flexibleSpace: Stack(
children: [
Positioned(
child: Image(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
image: NetworkImage(
widget.details,
),
),
top: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
bottom: 0),
Positioned(
child: Container(
height: 20,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
boxShadow: [
BoxShadow(
color: const Color(0x29000000),
offset: Offset(0, -8),
blurRadius: 15,
),
],
color: Colors.white,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
top: Radius.circular(50),
),
),
),
bottom: -1,
left: 0,
right: 0,
),
],
),
expandedHeight: 450.0,
),
SliverList(
delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
(BuildContext context, int index) {
return overView();
}, childCount: 1),
),
],